# ORM create() behavior to automatically convert "file values" to filename on database save

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

given this:

```
// controller
$post = $this->request->post() + $_FILES;

// $_FILES['photo'] is the file array
$object = orm::factory('item')->values($post, array('name', 'photo');
$object->create();

// model
public function rules()
{
        return array(
        'photo' => array(
            array('Upload::not_empty'),
            array('Upload::valid'),
            array('Upload::type', array(':value', array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'))),
            array('Upload::size', array(':value', '2M'))
        )
    );
}
```

I was wondering if anyone has implemented a hack for the ORM's create() method to automatically assign to the database's "photo" field the file name ($_FILES['field']['name']) retrieved from the photo $_FILES array? Or I should just do the standard manually validate then create?

Comment: What actual file name from `$_FILES`? There are several per entry.

Comment: $_FILES['photo']['name']

Comment: You can try with filters. You can add filter functions to execute over fields when they are modified. [Kohana ORM Filters docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/filters)